# Help with silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have some methods which are not compiled with Silverlight framework but are very essential for execution of SL workflow(by workflow, I mean to process my application completely). What is the best/quickest way to do so? 
I was thinking of publishing a web-service(for non-sl compiled methods) and make SL call into my WS.. but I am unable to see/create webservice instance even after registering one in my SL project. (I am using VS 2010)
any help?

Comment: do you have access to these other methods? i mean, the code for them?

Comment: yes, I have access to the methods. Btw I am new to webservices and SL.. so please bare with  me :)

Comment: if you have the code, you should put the methods into a class in the application, and call them that way

Answer (score 0):

Esentially, you have three ways to run code.

native built-in methods in your application--this would be the easiest way

methods that live in an external silverlight assembly, like a class library

use a webservice

if you use a webservice, you have to either host the website yourself or use a 3rd party website, then add a reference to said service. if the service is not hosted on the same website as your silverlight app, there **must** be a [cross-domain policy file](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/how-to-use-cross-domain-policy-files-with-silverlight/) in place otherwise silverlight will not use the service.

if you use an external assembly, it **MUST** be a silverlight assembly. you can not use a windows class library, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common (and relatively easy) way to solve this issue without requiring a web service: you can create a new Silverlight class library and then share the files from the other project through to your new Silverlight library.

To do this, right click on the library in the Solution Explorer, and select *Add -> Existing Item*, then navigate to the appropriate code file, select it, **but instead of just clicking** *Add* you should instead click the little down arrow and select *Add As Link*.

Of course when you do this you have to ensure that the shared files don't contain anything that cannot be compiled targeting the Silverlight runtime, if they do then you will either have to use conditional compilation directives to isolate out that code, or revert to the web service option.